# Disable or customize fields in Checkout Form in Magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

**How can I disable all fields in the checkout form?**

I want the checkout form as it already exists in Magento 2, but with fields that cannot be edited by the user.

These fields will be loaded externally, so I need them not to be edited but the client can see them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some tricky,way we can do

**add a phtml from layout**

```
#app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="disabled.all" as="disabled.js" template="Magento_Checkout::js.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**Then disabledjs.phtml add below code for disabled all fields**

```
##app/design/frontend/Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/templates/disabledjs.phtml
<script>
require(['jquery', 'loadingPopup', 'prototype'], function(jQuery){

//<![CDATA[

jQuery(document).readyd(function() {
   $("input,select,button").prop("disabled", true);
});
//]]>

});
</script>
```

Comment: I probe this, but it don't work to me :(

Comment: It charge the js but the prop not works

Comment: I put an alert in the js and js load before the form load. It is the problem